# Validate private properties using ValidationAttributes in .net 4

Tags: .net-4.0, validationattribute

I have classes which get private properties set via the constructor.

I would then like to run the following code from a base class to check if the passed values are ok: 
ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);

> ValidationResults = new
>   List();
>
> ```
> if (!System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.TryValidateObject(this, context, ValidationResults, true))
> {
>     this.Success = false;
>     this.StatusCode = CommandStatusCode.ValidationFailed;
>     return false;
> }
> return true;
> ```

Problem is, the TryValidateObject only validates public properties. Is there any way of getting private properties validated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use code contracts on your constructor's arguments.

Comment: Haven't done anything with code contracts yes, but looks promising... Is there a simple way to resuse ValidationAttributes, which I all have coded allready, for code contracts?

Comment: @AyKarsi: Code Contracts are conditionally-compiled, and potentially even statically-checked by compiler.  Attributes are verified with reflection-based mechanisms at run-time.  Do you have a spec?  If so, you could write unit tests or code contracts, or a mix.